# How to browse sitecore project as anonymous user

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have built a sitecore site in my dev PC and published it. (From `master` to `web` database).
How can I browse the site as an anonymous user.

Say, if i browse the url `mysite/pages/about`, it loads the page but within the sitecore shell. (and also, I need to be logged in)

I would like to see it, as if it went live. Is this possible.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are still logged into Sitecore by default it will use those credentials to load the page in "Edit Mode".

Use a different browser or open a tab in incognito/private browsing mode.

Alternatively, in Experience Explorer from the Home Ribbon section select "Close" or append `?sc_mode=normal` to the URL of the page.

There is a cookie named `website#sc_mode` which will also be set to `Edit` when you are in Experience Editor, which remembers your last selection. You could also try removing this as well as the other Sitecore cookies.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a SiteDefinion.config file in the App_Config/Include folder, which is not avilable by default.
Lets say, the sitecore instance name is *democore* and you have to develop a website - *mysite*.

And your content tree may be structured as :

Sitecore > Content > MySite > (home, about, contact etc)
This config file will have the following configuration

```xml
    <configuration xmlns:patch="www.sitecore.net/.../">
    <sitecore>
        <sites>
            <site patch:before="*[@name='website']"
            name="/"
            hostname="democore"
            virtualfolder="/"
            physicalfolder="/"
            rootpath="/sitecore/content/"
            mediapath="/sitecore/media library/mysite/"
            startitem="/home"
            loginpage="/login"
            database="web"
            domain="extranet"
            allowdebug="false"
            cachehtml="false"
            htmlcachesize="10MB"
            registrycachesize="0"
            viewstatecachesize="0"
            xslcachesize="5MB"
            filtereditemscachesize="2MB"
            enablepreview="true"
            enablewebedit="true"
            enabledebugger="false"
            disableclientdata="false"
            language="en"
            usedisplayname="true"
            embedlanguage="false"
            embedlanguageinmedia="true"
            routesitename="mysite" />
        </sites>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You can now browse the site as `democore/mysite/home`